# Formatting cells in excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I have excel sheets with thousands rows and columns of numeric data, and need to do some calculations on this data. But in few files there is a cell or two which have their format as text even when  they contain a number. The data is so huge that it is not possible to check each and every cell for the format. So is there a way I could rectify these errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excell 2007 or later, use search and replace.

Leave `Find What` and `Replace with` blank, select `Text` in the find what format, and `General` (or other numeric format) in the replace with format.

Run `Replace All` and its done!

Answer (score 0):

Use ASAP utilities www.asap-utilities.com/

They have macro to turn text into numbers

You could also use the value function

```
=value(A1)
```

Which converts text to numbers

Answer (score 0):

I would start by selecting the particular row/column headers you wish to have formatted as numbers.  Then, just choose "Number" from the drop down menu that allows you to select the cell type.  This will apply the format the all value cells in that particular row/column.

This is of course assuming that all cells read as text will be valid numbers.  Otherwise, you'll have to employ additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Or, copy the values to a new worksheet, but before it, you need format all cells to number format and use the "Paste Special" option, choosing the "Values" dialog options.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any formulas, just values, you could run this code

```
Sub MakeValues()

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.NumberFormat = "General"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

End Sub
```